# tikz distribution and contour plot from seaborn

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a generated a contour plot from 2 density estimations using seaborn. I want to reproduce the plot using tikz, but I don't find any resources. [image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Edit: here is a sample of the data

```
 X 
102.676
78.5586
79.6868
82.5308
91.4554
93.5447
76.1719
66.3583
65.6621
0.746499
79.8957
0.850208
1.22866
104.088
36.3896
81.0653
94.9967
60.7178
96.3762
26.597
104.794
77.087
106.279
77.5906
43.9731
112.355
92.8647
92.1753
82.8094
105.941
47.7353
28.5966
89.6883
88.8432
105.329
82.1814
34.0755
96.8788
76.9557
46.4801
77.4166
81.6322
64.593
78.3
111.075
97.762
107.732
90.5405
67.6399
0.746499
42.7024
101.782
83.0307
73.2556
68.4083
57.8238
66.0233
39.0776
71.2586
70.5701
0.850208
87.5717
62.1982
109.8
1.22866
81.2693
83.7004
110.437
90.2362
80.5196
94.9327
69.5344
89.2766
61.7433
74.558
90.8988
67.9168
107.35
108.054
92.4359
99.6905
41.9103
78.3808
79.0937
59.2144
65.5379
56.6337
56.9718
107.554
42.5465
56.2624
63.5392
77.1599
74.6713
62.1982
52.2043
78.8423
43.819
59.56
65.5032
42.7706
61.8486
41.5089
38.5357
70.9904
86.0314
109.952
100.993
60.4296
0.099839
73.9194
61.7402
88.9099
63.9207
43.0294
62.519
86.3689
58.9263
41.7816
84.8238
71.8382
36.0272
-0.928131
-0.8
75.3791

Y
102.51
79.72
80.21
81.12
97.31
100.18
78.82
65.74
64.72
10.54
78.72
10.54
10.54
102.51
36.64
80.21
101.08
66.96
102.99
26.61
102.51
83.02
105.93
78.82
44.85
110.61
100.26
100.26
82.18
114.12
54.92
29.54
90.07
94.78
103.37
81.08
34.78
103.64
79.43
52.38
77.16
79.92
64.39
78.82
118.49
102.99
115.78
95.06
67.35
7.22
49.61
108.24
88.76
79.44
73.88
56.84
71.72
41.05
75.41
75.41
7.22
94.78
66.41
118.49
7.22
79.58
88.76
118.49
92.84
79.43
100.26
67.35
95.06
61.46
82.3
92.84
70.32
114.12
114.12
95.06
107.76
49.89
79.43
79.43
62.67
64.98
56.41
55.81
105.93
49.89
55.81
66.41
83.52
79.44
69.17
57.49
78.2
49.89
58.99
72.35
42.04
67.98
42.04
40.55
70.3
91.48
108.28
107.76
65.02
2.8
82.3
67.46
92.84
64.09
49.45
67.98
84.58
66.54
49.45
84.29
76.55
36.5
1.33
-0.140002
79.44
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! While it is certainly possible to draw something like this, you will have much better chances to get a real answer if you provide us with what you have tried and at the very least with the data.

Comment: @marmot thank you for your comment. I have added a sample of the data. Actually I have 2 Variable X and Y. I need to plot the distribution of each variable and the do a contour plot, or a surf plot :)

Comment: I think you want to use a `contour plot` from pgfplots for the contours.

Comment: Just to let you know that the data is not in a good format for pgfplots. Maybe some good soul will convert it for you. However, if you wish a larger group of users to look at your question, please consider preparing a contour plot (see section **4.6.9 Filled Contour Plots** of the pgfplots manual). Then your question will be "only" on how to add the plots on the horizontal and vertical axes, but this will be a well-defined and interesting question.